# Calculate average of a flat array

Tags: php, arrays, count, sum, average

Looking to calculate average of my `$data` array.  I need to first find the sum of the values in the array, then divide that by the total nimber of elements.

Here's what I have, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($data as $value) {
    $sum = $sum+$value;
    return $sum;
}
$count = count($data);

$average = $sum / $count;
echo "Average is $average <br />";
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$total = array_sum($data);
$average = $total / count($data);
```

Or, if you like one-liners:

```
$average = array_sum($data) / count($data);
```

Answer (score 4):

remove the `return`

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($data as $value) {
        $sum = $sum+$value;

}
$count = count($data);

$average = $sum / $count;
echo "Average is $average <br />";
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason it's failing is that you shouldn't have the `return` statement. `return` is only used for returning from functions.

That said, you can just use `array_sum()` instead.